# Value cannot be null, Parameter name: viewInfo

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

After installing SP2 to an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 I lost access to all my databases and started facing the error in the screenshot.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the workarounds here http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/573771/value-cannot-be-null#

Comment: Another reason is disk space. The stack trace tells you as much so it's not a mystery

Comment: Note: the above link no longer works since microsoft connect was recently retired.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check the environment value for **Temp** and **TMP**.

`C:\Users\buck>set t`

`TEMP=C:\Users\buck\AppData\Local\Temp\2`

`TMP=C:\Users\buck\AppData\Local\Temp\2`

Make sure the directory listed exist and your id has appropriate permission to write to that directory. Alternatively, through the control panel (`Control Panel-> System and Security-> System -> Advanced system settings`), you can change the default directories that are assigned to **TEMP** and **TMP**.

Comment: I just discovered that after "Windows update", the temp directory changed to what ever it was + '\2' like in this example!!!
I just had to reset and that solved my problem.

Comment: Every couple of weeks my temp\2 folder goes missing and this error starts to occur.  Recreating the folder solves the problem immediately; no system reboot necessary.  I have no idea why this keeps happening but it is infuriating

Comment: Just re added the Temp/2 folder

Comment: This solution worked for me and help a lot. :) in my case folder 2 was missing, now why it was missing that is the question :)

Comment: The fact that SSMS cannot start unless there is an empty folder named `2` inside `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` is somewhere between funny and disturbing.

Answer (score 22):

When I've seen this issue, it is usually because the Drive that SSMS is installed on has run out of free space. Deleting some old Log files clears the issue up.

Doing that quick check might be worthwhile before going forward with a re-install.

Answer (score 11):

I got this error on our remote shared server. Turned out that our C drive did not have any space left.

I got it working by asking my colleague to close his SQL Server Management Studio session and it cleared up 7 GB right away! I could login then! Woot woot!

Comment: Thank you ! it helped in troubleshooting

Comment: Helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When running into this I found it was related to the environment temp folder (TMP Temp).

I had tried adding the "2" folder to this location with no success.
`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2`

Try typing `%temp%` in file explorer and see if it takes you to a valid location. I found that I received an error because it was trying to go to a "4" location. 
`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\4`

I created a folder named "4" in the Temp folder, reran SSMS, and it started working again.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the SSMS icon and click 'run as administrator'. At the SSMS console verify that the error is gone by clicking on the 'Databases' tree node. The error should now be permanently fixed and you do not need to run SSMS as admin anymore. Next time just start SSMS normally and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the temp variables did not resolve. Drive with SMMS installed has 34% free space.

However, using `Run > %temp% > it` would error out as `"C:\%username%\appdata\local\temp\4 was missing"` (this is not listed in my `TEMP/TMP` variables).

Quick solution was to add sub folder for "4" in `c:\%username%\appdata\local\temp\` and now able to open SMMS without issue.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google suggest that apparently it is a bit common issue. It looks like that it is not an issue of SQL Server itself but actually .NET issue And most common (and quick) solution I found is to reinstall SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you are upgrading an iseries odbc driver on a sql cluster. Lots of times you will run into this issue exactly. Renaming the machine.config in both the 32 bit and 64 bit folders does the trick. we currently upgraded from version 12 or 6.1 to 7.1 or 13 as the version 12 was causing a bug check on one of our SQL instances. Upgraded, and the issues all went away.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

According to the following link:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/573771/value-cannot-be-null

I just checked that my user is local admin, then i logged off and logged back in.
After that step i haven't received this error again.

Comment: The above link no longer works since microsoft connect was recently retired.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this exact error and thought I'd have a go at running the repair.

Well the repair didn't resolve the issue however it did tell me that it was unable to access machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG - found it didn't exist! There was another file machine.config.default

So had a stab at copying, renaming to .config and viola resolved it and everything working like a champion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in SSMS and I found [this link](http://mssqlnuggets.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-viewinfo-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sqlstudio-explorer/) and followed the steps as it mentioned.

> The problem appeared to be when accessing the contents of a settings file. The file had invalid entries. This file is CurrentSettings-. The fix for this is as shown below:
>
> 1. On the server Go to start menu–>Your profile–>Documents–>SQL Server Management Studio–>Settings (this is the location of the file specified above)
> 2. Delete all files from this folder
> 3. Restart sqlserver services
> 4. Launch the SSMS and this error is gone. You will be able to expand all the folders and perform regular SSMS activities without this error.

Once I performed these steps and restarted my PC this error was gone and SSMS worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue and resolved it immediately in 5 mins. Just go to Control Panel and Run Troubleshooting tool on Programs.

```
**PATH** Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\Programs
```

It will give you the list of installed programs which may have any issue. Scroll down that list and find 'SQL Server Management Studio' and run troubleshooting process on that. It will hopefully fix you issue.

Answer (score 0):

I gets this messages many times and every time it is resolved by different solutions below few of it.

1. Solution: Clear cache from temp folder, Press windows + R => type "%temp%" => Delete all the files from temp folder... And try weather it works and opens ssms successfully
2. Solution: create folder named "2" in this above mentioned temp folder location... And try weather it works and opens ssms successfully.
3. Solution:create folder named "4" in this above mentioned temp folder location... And try weather it works and opens ssms successfully.
4. Solution: It may cause because of low disk space in drive ssms is installed... so free some space...And try weather it works and opens ssms successfully.
5. Solution: Format is the last solution...